# Can a Tensorflow Variable be created from shared memory?

Tags: c, tensorflow, shared-memory

I guess I could use the `TF_NewTensor(..., void* data,...)` function (from the The Tensorflow C API) to create a new tensor from shared memory by having `data` point to the shared memory. If I pass that tensor to `tf.Vaiable()`, will the Tensorflow variable store its data in, and read it from, the shared memory? If not, is it possible to get a pointer to the variable´s underlying data buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, TensorFlow needs to own the Tensor buffers, because they are refcounted internally by the system based on their use.  We do not have an API to transfer ownership of an existing buffer to a Tensor, though feel free to file a feature request on GitHub for this.